# Can I change the position of swipeable tabs in android?

Tags: android, tabs, positioning

I am new to android so please suggest how I can do the following. I need a text box above a tab view for which I need to position the tab view. I used ViewPager after learning a bit of it online. Can anyone suggest me anything to get what I need?
I have attached an image for what I wish to create on an activity.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4YOVOcFR_ChVzVoekJQbjZud3c

Comment: You can create search on action bar.Is that ok?http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: @user2217535 I won't be keeping the action bar. The action bar will be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use search view,tablayout and view pager together

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SearchViewActivity" >

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</SearchView>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

you may look at theese links

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml

https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/android-searchview-tutorial-edittext-with-phone-contacts-search-and-autosuggestion/